# C# Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I need a little help with a regex query that I can't seem to get to work.

I need to check the following format: string - integer

The string is passed into the method as a parameter called studyID, so it should check studyID - integer where '-' is a string literal, and there are spaces either side of it.

Can anybody please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try and what results did you get? Errors, wrong outcomes?

Comment: My latest attempt was regex = study.Id + "/s-/s/d";

Comment: And can you give some examples of actual values that this regex should work on?

Comment: You probably wanted `\s` not `/s`

Comment: And maybe `\d+` to capture more than one digit.

Comment: @duedl0r - yes that's what was wrong - damn stupid sleep deprived coding!!!  It seems to work...thanks!

Comment: @duedl0r - thanks for the info.  Make it an answer and I will accept.

Comment: And also, if you prepend study.Id to it, make sure that study.Id doesn't contain characters than can confuse the regex handler.

Comment: @Mr Lister - it should be a standard alpha string.  What should I be checking for in this case?  Thanks.

Comment: One site I like to use for Regex syntax is this one: http://txt2re.com
It can be very handy

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you. I'm assuming you are just looking for a match.

```
 Regex r = new Regex(study.Id + "(\\s+)(-)(\\s+)(\\d+)");
```

The \\s+ will handle any white space and \\d+ any integer.

Answer (score 2):

Special characters are escaped like this: `\s` and not `/s`. Also, if you want to match more than one digit you could do this: `\d+` to match at least one digit (comment from Howard).

Then assure yourself that `study.Id` has no "regex-characters" like `[]+*` and so on..

Answer (score 0):

for any string, followed by " - " and any number use this:

```
^(.+)(\s-\s)(\d+)$
```

for the string "studyID" in the beginning, use this:

```
^studyID(\s-\s)(\d+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining everything:

```
var re = new Regex("^" + Regex.Escape(study.Id) + @"\s+-\s+(\d+)\z");
```

Escaping the content of `study.Id`, allowing multiple number spaces around `-`, anchoring it to beginning/end of string. If the latter is not desired you can remove the `^` and `\z`.